# Duda por Fatal Error en phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Mi profesor quiere que realice lo que indica este enunciado:

> Obtener la clave de producto, nombre del producto y nombre del fabricante de todos los productos en venta

El código que ejecuto es este, que en principio debería servir:

```
SELECT articulos.Nombre, articulos.Precio, fabricantes.Nombre
FROM articulos,fabricantes
WHERE fabricantes.Nombre='Logitech' AND articulos.Clave_fabricante=fabricantes.Clave_fabricante
ORDER BY articulos.Precio ASC;
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el código, me salta un *Fatal Error*:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface::getColumns() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php on line 201 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php:1332 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(201): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->getColumns('tienda', NULL) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(1888): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->resultSetContainsUniqueKey('tienda', NULL, Array) #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(2271): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(Object(mysqli_result), Array, 'tienda', NULL, NULL, NULL, Object(PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results), './themes/metro/...', 3, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SELECT articulo...', NULL) #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(2117): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(Array, false, 'tienda', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'db_multi_table_...', './themes/metro/...', NULL in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 1332

---

Se me ha pedido que añada código php e imágenes. Bien, pues esto es todo lo que puedo ofrecer de información: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo código php porque estoy empezando en bases de datos y por el momento lo único que nos están pidiendo en clase es que hagamos consultas desde phpmyadmin. 
Siento no poder ofrecer mucho más... :(

Comment: ¿Seguro que hay un fabricante llamado "Logitech"?

Comment: Agrega tu código php

Comment: Es una buena practica probar el codigo SQL directamente en el motor de base de datos si te es posible para descartar errores de codigo. Te recomiendo utilizar MySql workbench o HeidiSQL para manejar tus bases de datos, asi te evitas el error de la capa web de phpmyadmin.

Comment: Si quers mas atencion, te recomiendo que mejores tu pregunta. asi como esta, le falta el codigo php que tira el error, una prueba de que ese query realmente en tu db y todo lo que haga falta para que la pregunta pueda ser contestada.

Comment: @rabisa47 Las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir una descripción de lo que se quiere hacer, el código mínimo para reproducir el problema y los errores que se estén recibiendo. Por favor, añade el código PHP relacionado al error, porque sin verlo, no es posible saber qué es exactamente lo que estás mal. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Coloca las capturas de tu tablas creadas así podríamos visualizar mejor esto.

Comment: ye he añadido más información, eso es todo lo que puedo aportar creo

Answer (score 0):

Para consultar dos o mas tablas simultaneamente se utiliza la Sentencia INNER JOIN, aqui mas o menos esta una modificacion  de tu codigo:

```
SELECT articulos.Nombre, articulos.Precio, fabricantes.Nombre
FROM articulos INNER JOIN fabricantes ON articulos.Clave_fabricante=fabricantes.Clave_fabricante 
WHERE fabricantes.Nombre='Logitech' AND 
ORDER BY articulos.Precio ASC;
```

Comment: Puedes omitir el uso de `AND` ya que `ORDER BY` es una clausula de ordenamiento el cual se va a realizar independientemente del resultado que devuelva la consulta el cual además por defecto ordena en forma ascendente.

Comment: No necesariamente se tiene que usar un INNER JOIN para consultar dos tablas a la vez, también se puede usar, por ejemplo, la sentencia UNION. Si las dos tablas se relacionan entre sí, entonces sí hay que utilizar las sentencias de relación.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes consultar a dos tablas a la vez en un solo FROM. Si las quieres unir debes usar un JOIN básico el cual enlazará las dos tablas en una sola consulta sql.

EJEMPLO:

```
SELECT articulos.Nombre, articulos.Precio, fabricantes.Nombre
FROM articulos
JOIN fabricantes
ON (articulos.Clave_fabricante = fabricantes.Clave_fabricante)
WHERE fabricantes.Nombre='Logitech'
ORDER BY articulos.Precio ASC;
```

No es necesario validar que sean iguales las claves de fabricantes dado que el JOIN utiliza esa identificación para hacer el match entre esas dos tablas.